# KEDA Scaling Down pod efficiently (check useractivity before scaling down)

Tags: spring, kubernetes, rabbitmq, keda

I have spring boot app that consume from rabbitmq I deployed this app on k8s and created keda file to scale it if the size of the queue pass x messages it work fine i got new pod created ,but now I want to make like a rule on the scale down part I want to make sure that there is no user using that pod before scale it down so i dont interpept any activity I searched on google and chatgpt I found something like prestop and readnessProbe ,Who Have an idea how this can be done I'll apreciate an kind of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that there is some limited time that your application need to process request like 45s from receiving request to complete.

In such case I would use `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` which by default is `30s` but you can extend it to any value.

What is happening under the hood is when `KEDA` will start scaling down and your pod will be in `Terminating` state it is immediately removed from `service` endpoint and it is not receiving new requests (if `service` exist for that pod). Then it will send `SIGTERM` signal and wait until process will finish it's work (please be sure that your application handle `SIGTERM` properly). After processing current request pod should be killed before time defined by `terminationGracePeriodSeconds`. If processing of request take longer than `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` it will just kill pod without waiting and message should go back to queue.

So if processing request is taking eg. `120s` sample manifest should looks like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 130
```

Comment: Hi,  when i use terminationGracePeriodSeconds it will wait 130 sec after the size of the queue back to normal or after the any users request terminated, for example if 100 sec passed and I got a request that take 50 sec it will count from the begining 130 sec ?

Comment: Hello. I edited my initial answer where I included information about `SIGTERM` which should prevent pod from consuming new messages from queue when it is terminated.

Comment: Hi, I actualy tried your suggestion i wanted to test so i created an get api that make an delay for 120 sec and i request this api before i provoke an scale down by removing a message from the queue but the pod still terminating after 30 seconds  `spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 120
      containers:
        - name: consumer-container
          image: elnalouti/sigrepo:tagname
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8087`
and about the SIGTREM ididnt now exactly what you mean so chatgpt provided me this code `  @PreDestroy
    public void onShutdown() {LOGGER.inf("")}`

Comment: Hi. I run small test with [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ContainerSolutions/kubernetes-examples/master/Pod/spec.terminationGracePeriodSeconds/simple.yaml) pod example. For first run I keep `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` to default `5` seconds and for second I change it to `100` seconds. Results where as expected since first pod was terminated after `5s` and second after `100s`. I run that on `minikube` `v1.29.0`.

Comment: Hi ,I think it worked thanks , but i just want to make sure if i got the expected the result the pod logs show that he terminate after 120 seconds but when i execute kubectl get deployment i see 1/1 after 30 sec this is normal right ? that mean it worked ?